# Connecting a 4 bit shift register output to a 4 bit input in another module in Verilog

Tags: verilog, vlsi

For our school project I am trying to use linear feedback shift register for pseudo-random number generation on hardware (seven segment). I have written the LFSR and seven segment module, however I have trouble connecting the two modules with each other. The project synthesizes but the HDL Diagram does not show any connection between LFSR and seven segment module. Below is the code.

```
//main module
module expo(input clock, reset,
            output a,b,c,d,e,f,g
            );
wire [3:0]connect, clk, a,b,c,d,e,f,g;

LFSR_4_bit lfsr(
    .clock(clock),
    .LFSR(connect)
);

seven_seg seven(
     .in(connect),
     .reset(reset),
     .a(a),
     .b(b),
     .c(c),
     .d(d),
     .e(e),
     .f(f),
     .g(g)
);

endmodule

 //LFSR module
 module LFSR_4_bit(
            input clock,
            output reg[3:0]LFSR = 15  
);

    wire feedback = LFSR[4];

    always @(posedge clock)
       begin
      LFSR[0] <= feedback;
      LFSR[1] <= LFSR[0];
      LFSR[2] <= LFSR[1];
      LFSR[3] <= LFSR[2] ^ feedback;
      LFSR[4] <= LFSR[3];
      end

  endmodule

  //input and output for seven seg module

module sevenseg(
    input reset,
    input[3:0] in,  //the 4 inputs for each display
    output a, b, c, d, e, f, g, //the individual LED output for the seven segment along                           with the digital point
    output [3:0] an   // the 4 bit enable signal
    );
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** You instantiate `seven_seg` but the module is called `module sevenseg` This is a compile error.

**2)** Your LFSR has 4 bits 0 to 3, a fifth bit `LFSR[4]` is used, this is also a compile error.

Due to the compile errors I am not sure that your viewing the results of the current synthesis, as it should have failed. It is quite likely that you are viewing an old result before they were connected.

Other things I would change:
**a)** When you define `wire [3:0]connect, clk, a,b,c,d,e,f,g;` they are all 4 bits.

However as clock (not clk) and `a,b,c,d,e,f,g` are defined in your port list they are already declared. That line could just be `wire [3:0]connect`.

**b)** When initialising values for flip-flop and not using a reset it is better practise to use an initial begin : This is valid for FPGA's not for ASICs where you should use reset signals

```
initial begin
  LFSR = 4'd15;
end
```

Comment: I think initial statements are usually used for implementing test benchs and are not synthesizable

Comment: And a reset signal would make your LFSR generate the same sequence of numbers each time it is turned on

Comment: @dasho lfsr's are expected to give the same sequence when turned on that is why they are pseudo random. Initial Statements are synthesisable and are used for setting defaults on fpgas.